# Is there a way to have the nav drawer list fill the height of the drawer without adding padding to the list items

Tags: android, layout, navigation-drawer

Like the title says is there a way either via xml or programmatically to have a list fill the height of the nav drawer if the list does not contain enough items.
For example if I have a list of 4 items with background color black, and the 4 items only take up half the height of the drawer the rest of the drawer is grey and looks silly.
I have countered this by increasing padding on each item, but its kinda hacky I think. Plus I have to increase the padding quite a bit on higher density devices I want to support.

In the case of the posted code I have added 22dp of padding for an xxhdpi device.
Any tips are appreciated.
Thanks.

Drawer XML

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/black"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="false"/>



</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Drawer Items xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:paddingTop="22dp"
         android:paddingBottom="22dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_icon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:padding="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/item_icon"
        android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:textColor="#fff"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a static number of items? If so, you can easily get the total height of the ListView and divide it by the amount of items. Then, you set the item height to each row.

If you have a dynamic number of items it's a little bit more tricky, because you have to determine a minimum height for a row in order to display all this content and only set the calculated row height if it's greater than the determined minimum.